# PL-SQL Displaying multiple rows

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to **display multiple-rows** from a table but it displays an error when i run the script. I'm using **ORACLE 11g: SQL Developer**

*ERRORS:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS.OUTPUT' must be declared*

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_ALL_CUSTOMERS AS

  T_CUST_LASTNAME CUSTOMERS.LASTNAME%TYPE;
  T_CUST_FIRSTNAME CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
  T_ORD_ORDERDATE ORDERS.ORDERDATE%TYPE;
  T_ORD_SHIPDATE ORDERS.SHIPDATE%TYPE;
  T_TOT_CUST INTEGER:=0;

CURSOR CUST_CURSOR IS
  SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
  FROM CUSTOMERS;

BEGIN

  OPEN CUST_CURSOR; 

  LOOP
    FETCH CUST_CURSOR INTO T_CUST_LASTNAME, T_CUST_FIRSTNAME;

  EXIT WHEN CUST_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || T_CUST_LASTNAME || ', ' || T_CUST_FIRSTNAME);

T_TOT_CUST := T_TOT_CUST + 1;

END LOOP;

CLOSE CUST_CURSOR;

DBMS.OUTPUT.PRINT_LINE('');
DBMS.OUTPUT.PRINT_LINE('NUMBER OF CUSTOMERS: ' || T_TOT_CUST);
END;
/

BEGIN
PRINT_ALL_CUSTOMERS;
END;
```

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT` instead of `DBMS.OUTPUT`

Answer (score 1):

it is `PUT_LINE()` method in `DBMS_OUTPUT` package

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF CUSTOMERS: ' || T_TOT_CUST);
```